# "%s: invalid identifier" when creating table

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I am trying to create a table for class and not quite sure why i'm getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS_CHECK
(
  NUMERO NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  DIRECCION NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  DISTANCIA NUMBER(3),
  OFICIO VARCHAR2(15),
  TELEFONO_FIJO VARCHAR2(9),
  TELEFONO_MOVIL VARCHAR2(9),
  FECHA_NAC DATE,
  FECHA_ALTA DEFAULT(SYSDATE),
  DEPT NUMBER(3),
  NUM_HIJOS NUMBER(2),
  TITULADO CHAR(1),
  SALARIO NUMBER(6),

  CONSTRAINT CK_NUMERO CHECK (NUMERO BETWEEN 1 AND 10000),
  CONSTRAINT CK_TEL_FIJO CHECK (TELEFONO_FIJO LIKE '91%'),
  CONSTRAINT CK_TEL_MOVIL CHECK (TELEFONO_MOVIL LIKE '6%'),
  CONSTRAINT CK_OFICIO CHECK (OFICIO IN ('VENDEDOR','GERENTE', 'OTROS')),

  CONSTRAINT CK_FECHA_NAC CHECK (FECHA_NAC < '01/01/1990'),

  CONSTRAINT CK_DEPT_CATEGORY CHECK (DEPT IN ('10','20', '30')),
  CONSTRAINT CK_DEPT_NUMBER CHECK (DEPT BETWEEN 1 AND 100),

  CONSTRAINT CK_NUM_HIJOS_QUANTITY DEFAULT(0) CHECK(NUM_HIJOS <= 10),
  CONSTRAINT CK_NUM_HIJOS_RANGE CHECK (NUM_HIJOS BETWEEN 1 AND 10),

  CONSTRAINT CK_TITULADO DEFAULT('N') CHECK (TITULADO IN ('S','N'))
);
```

Do let me know what i'm doing wrong!

Comment: Works without any problem for me. So the issue is not in the sql code. Must be something outside, like how you try to load / execute that code.

Comment: I'd say the CONSTRAINT CK_TITULADO DEFAULT('N') is suspicious. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I've replaced the MySQL tag with an Oracle one. If you are actually running Oracle code against MySQL, that'd explain any problem you have. It's also worth nothing that the ORA-#### code you're carefully ignoring is possibly the most important piece of info Oracle provides.

Answer (score -2):

Hm, it seems after a bit of fiddling around the code I finally got around to creating it. This is what I used for it to succesfully let me generate a table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS_CHECK
(
  NUMERO NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  DIRECCION NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  DISTANCIA NUMBER(3),
  OFICIO VARCHAR2(15),
  TELEFONO_FIJO VARCHAR2(9),
  TELEFONO_MOVIL VARCHAR2(9),
  FECHA_NAC DATE,
  FECHA_ALTA DATE DEFAULT(SYSDATE),
  DEPT NUMBER(3),
  NUM_HIJOS NUMBER(2) DEFAULT(0) ,
  TITULADO CHAR(1) DEFAULT('N'),
  SALARIO NUMBER(6),

  CONSTRAINT CK_NUMERO CHECK (NUMERO BETWEEN 1 AND 10000),
  CONSTRAINT CK_TEL_FIJO CHECK (TELEFONO_FIJO LIKE '91%'),
  CONSTRAINT CK_TEL_MOVIL CHECK (TELEFONO_MOVIL LIKE '6%'),
  CONSTRAINT CK_OFICIO CHECK (OFICIO IN ('VENDEDOR','GERENTE', 'OTROS')),
  CONSTRAINT CK_FECHA_NAC CHECK (to_char(FECHA_NAC, 'yyyy') < 1990),
  CONSTRAINT CK_DEPT_CATEGORY CHECK (DEPT IN ('10','20', '30')),
  CONSTRAINT CK_DEPT_NUMBER CHECK (DEPT BETWEEN 1 AND 100),
  CONSTRAINT CK_NUM_HIJOS_QUANTITY CHECK (NUM_HIJOS <= 10),
  CONSTRAINT CK_NUM_HIJOS_RANGE CHECK (NUM_HIJOS BETWEEN 1 AND 10),
  CONSTRAINT CK_TITULADO CHECK (TITULADO IN ('S','N'))
);
```

Thanks to both of the answers! I appreciate the interest.

Comment: Care to explain (via http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33890182/edit) a little further what was wrong with your code? I mean, to avoid people having to run `diff` against your question and answer.